# HTML5 Video playback not working with Safari (Mac and iOS)

Tags: html, video, safari, mobile-safari

I have some videos on one of my websites. Videos are using HTML5 video tag and used best practices while rendering tags. It works just fine in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and even Internet Explorer. Except Safari! Even Facebook detect video and sharing works perfect.

In Safari, it detects the video, loads browser controls, but the play do not work. I don't think that its a problem with video tag, because when I open the video in new tab, it do not work either. I have tried to re-encode the video, using `miro video converter` and settings for Apple, but nothing changed. I can download the video and play it with `Mac Preview` without any problems.

As additional information, I am using ASP.net on IIS 7.

I see this error in console: `Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load`

Here is one of the pages: https://www.parscanada.com/_104189

Here is the screen shot of the page on Safari for Mac:
[image: screen shot of the page on Safari for Mac]

And here is the screen shot of the page on Safari for iOS (Emulator - Same as device):
[image: screen shot of the page on Safari for iOS (Emulator - Same as device)]

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same problem. I just checked your website in Safari/iOS and the video-file seems to be working. Can you please explain how you managed to fix the issue?

Comment: Oops, sorry for not updating the answer. I'll post the answer in few minutes.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem solved, using the code from Scott Mitchel in http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx (link is dead, but you can find it in [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170625215430/http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx))

It seems to be a problem with sending correct headers back to Safari requests. I replaced parts of Scott's code with my original code and everything seems to work fine.

Here is scot's code summary:

```
/// <summary>
/// An abstract HTTP Handler that provides resumable file downloads in ASP.NET.
/// 
/// Created by:
///     Scott Mitchell
///     mitchell@4guysfromrolla.com
///     http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/ScottMitchell.shtml
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This class is a fairly close port of Alexander Schaaf's ZIPHandler HTTP Handler, which I found online at:
/// 
///     Tracking and Resuming Large File Downloads in ASP.NET
///     http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22533/1954
/// 
/// I also found a similar version of this code in the download for the September 2006 issue of MSDN Magazine:
/// http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/MSDNMag2006_09.exe
/// 
/// Alexander's code is in Visual Basic and was written for ASP.NET version 1.x. I ported the code to C#,
/// refactored portions of the code, and made use of functionality and features introduced in .NET 2.0 and 3.5.
/// </remarks>
```

Comment: Hi KiNG. I would love to see the final handler code. I am experiencing a similar problem (in a node.js-project) but maybe your code gives me some insight in which headers I should use.

Comment: Hi @Simon, sorry for late answer. I have used and extended Scott Mitchell's sample code. Since you are using node.js, my own code will not help you. Just download the sample code in above link and take a look at RangeRequestHandlerBase.cs. Its where you need to look at for finding proper headers and so.

Comment: You need to post the solution in your answer for this to be helpful. The linked site is now inaccessible, making this answer useless.

Comment: @NeilMonroe the complete answer is pretty long. I might post it as gist. :)

Comment: Why not just post the final handler code without forcing people to post a comment?

Comment: @NeilMonroe The original article can still be found at: http://web.archive.org/web/20170606093418/http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx

Comment: @MyPetYeti The original article can still be found at: http://web.archive.org/web/20170606093418/http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx

Comment: @Simon The original article can still be found at: http://web.archive.org/web/20170606093418/http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I cant post my final code, because I have integrated it with my existing handler and make lots of changes.